# Unity. controlling getcomponent with keyboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginer and have a problem with coding Unity. I want to show and hide 3D text meshes using two arrow keys. one mesh at once. but it doesn't work as I thought. I think you will easily find out what problem is.
and one more question. It will be worked at mobile device and dozens of meshes are going to be used. I'm not sure this is the best way, so please tell me if there is better. (especially about performance and optimization issue) thanks to read.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextmeshSelection : MonoBehaviour{
public List <GameObject> Textmeshes = new List<GameObject> ();
public int Num;

void Update() {
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
  Num++;
  Renderer rend = Textmeshes[Num].GetComponent<Renderer> ();
  if (rend.enabled)
   rend.enabled = false;
  else
   rend.enabled = true;
 }

 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
  Num--;
  Renderer rend = Textmeshes[Num].GetComponent<Renderer> ();
  if (rend.enabled)
   rend.enabled = false;
  else
   rend.enabled = true;
 }

 if (Num < 0) {
  Num = 0;
  Renderer rend = Textmeshes[Num].GetComponent<Renderer> ();
  if (rend.enabled)
   rend.enabled = false;
  else
   rend.enabled = true;
 }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `GetComponent` every time in `Update` but instead initialize all of them once e.g. in a dictionary

```
// Dictionary to store the references to the Renderer components
// Makes it easier to find them later
// You could as well only use a List instead and rely on the index
Dictionary<GameObject, Renderer> renderers = new Dictionary<GameObject, Renderer>();

private void Awake()
{
    // Get all references already at app start
    foreach(var textMesh in Textmeshes)
    {
        renderers[textMesh] = textMesh.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        // And hide all from beginning
        renderers[textMesh].enabled = false;
    }

    // Then enable only the first one depending what your Num is at start
    SanatizeNum();
    SetRendererEnabled(Num, true);
}
```

Then I would extract your code from `Update` into multiple methods to make it cleaner, remove redundancy and make it easier to maintain.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
    {
        GoToNext();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
    {
        GoToLast();
    }
}

private void GoToNext()
{
    // Hide the current renderer
    SetRendererEnabled(Num, false);

    Num++;
    SanatizeNum();

    // Show the new renderer
    SetRendererEnabled(Num, true);
}

private void GoToLast()
{
    SetRendererEnabled(Num, false);

    Num--;
    SanatizeNum();

    SetRendererEnabled(Num, true);
}

private void SanatizeNum()
{
    Num = Mathf.Clamp(Num, 0, Textmeshes.Count -1);
}

private void SetRendererEnabled(int index, bool enabled)
{
    renderers[Textmeshes[index]].enabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: thanks. removed () from this. '<GameObject, Renderer>() renderers  = ' but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: @arrddon Sorry I hacked this in on my smartphone ;) to be honest I completely forgot that you wanted to show only one `Renderer` at once. Please see my updated answer: before showing a new `Renderer` first disable the current one

Comment: you are my big helper thank you so much! now it works good. maybe last question - how can I set the limiter for 'int Num' controlled by keys? when number of 'int Num' exceeds the size of the List, It turns not to be controlled any more.

Comment: please check again. I still had a little mistake in `SanatizeNum`: the index `Num` ofcourse has to have maximum `Textmeshes.Count - 1` so it can not exceed the limit